# CLT for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Assume $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}$, $P(Y_n\leq y)\rightarrow\Phi(y)$ and if $n\rightarrow\infty$, $x_n\rightarrow x$, prove $P(Y_n\leq x_n)\rightarrow\Phi(x)$ if $x_n\rightarrow\infty$. It seems very intuitive, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: What is $x$? Did you mean $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: ah thanks! I didnt see it, its corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the normal distribution function $\Phi(x)$ is a continuous function, hence by Polya's theorem, $\mathsf{P}(Y_n\le y)\to \Phi(y)$ uniformly in $y$, that is 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}|\mathsf{P}(Y_n\le y)- \Phi(y)|=0.  $$
Therefore,
\begin{align}  |\mathsf{P}(Y_n\le x_n)- \Phi(x)|&\le |\mathsf{P}(Y_n\le x_n)-\Phi(x_n)|+|\Phi(x_n)-\Phi(x)|\\
&\le \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}|\mathsf{P}(Y_n\le y)- \Phi(y)|+|\Phi(x_n)-\Phi(x)|.\tag{1}
\end{align}
From (1) it is easy to get what you want.